Evaluating $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac h{\lVert h\rVert}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$
Basically the title, I want to evaluate $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{h}{\lVert h \rVert}$ where $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
I believe it’s equal to a norm vector where every $h_i$ is equal. However, I’m not sure if this is true or how you would evaluate. To me, the limit of each $\frac{h_i}{\lVert h \rVert}$ is too hard to evaluate since it would depend on the rates of convergence of the other ones, but I think this could also be a hint that the limit doesn’t exist at all. Does anyone have any hints?

It doesn't exist when $n=1$.  Use the same argument in the final coordinate for general $n$.

What is a "norm vector"?

@jjagmath I think “unit vector” is a more commonly used term but in my class we call it a “norm vector” i’m not sure why. It’s just any vector where the norm is 1.

If the limit exists, the composition of limits property should hold. Having said that, suppose the limit exists. Then, if we consider $h = tv$ for some $v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\{0\}$, the following limit should exist:
\begin{align*}
L = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{tv}{\|tv\|} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t}{|t|}\frac{v}{\|v\|}
\end{align*}
which is not the case, since the one-sided limits are not equal. Indeed, the first of them is given by:
\begin{align*}
L = \lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\frac{t}{|t|}\frac{v}{\|v\|} = \frac{v}{\|v\|}
\end{align*}
whereas the other one-sided limit is given by:
\begin{align*}
L = \lim_{t\to 0^{-}}\frac{t}{|t|}\frac{v}{\|v\|} = -\frac{v}{\|v\|}
\end{align*}
which leads to a contradiction, and we are done.
Hopefully this helps!

Notice that the form in the limit is a generalization of $\frac{a}{|a|}\in\mathbb{R}$, and it is clear that the limit of that $\frac{a}{|a|}$ at $0$ doesn't exist, thus we can try to show that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h}{\|h\|}$ also doesn't exists.
Now since the denominator is always positive, consider $h=(-c,\ldots,-c)$ and $h=(c,\ldots,c)$ for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
